# Browser tab storage?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, storage

Is there a browser storage that is usable only by the page that created it?

I'm making a TamperMonkey script to automate my work. It is triggered when a page from a specific domain is opened. It would then find a specific link (same domain) in said page and open it in the same tab. If the newly opened page matches a condition, it would go back to the previous page (to be checked manually). If it doesn't, then it would close itself.

I used localStorage to mark if a page has tried to do this check. Otherwise, the script would re-open the link when the original page is loaded and got caught in a loop.

The script runs smoothly when only a single tab is running. But it often fails when I run multiple tabs (all in the same domain). I'm guessing that each tab could access the same localStorage, thus messing with the loop check. I have not found anyway to give a unique name through the same script to each tab's localStorage.

As such, I need a browser storage that could be used by a tab even after it opened a new url in the same domain, but not usable by another tab which has the same domain.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) ?

Comment: I got the impression that sessionStorage is simply localStorage that got deleted after a session is over. Is there any other difference between the two?

Comment: well for your case, yes. sessions are shared only between the main window and windows opened by it.

Comment: I've solved the problem. Turns out it's a conflict with another script. Everything is smooth now. Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for this purpose.

**Example**

```js
// Store in `name` in the current tab

sessionStorage.setItem('name', 'Some Name');

// Get `name` from sessionStorage

var name = sessionStorage.getItem('name');


alert(name); // Some Name
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. **Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated**, which differs from how session cookies work.

Comment: What if multiple tabs are running the script simultaneously? My script fails when it runs under that condition. I suspect it's either because a) a newly opened tab have access to another tab's localStorage and modified it or b) the localStorage is wiped clean whenever a new tab is opened. All of these tabs are from the same domain and running the same script, thus creating and modifying localStorage with the same name.

Comment: @RayArifin There is a difference between `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`
if you use `sessionStorage` then if the user open two tabs there is no problem. every tab has it's own `sessionStorage` .